# jstree not moving a node after dropping

Tags: jquery, jstree

I'm trying to setup drag n drop inside a jstree. I want it so that the nodes can only be moved, not reordered.

My `check_move` function looks like this:

```
"crrm" : {
    "move" : {
        "check_move" : function (m) {
            if(m.p == "inside")
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
},
```

However this doesn't appear to be working. The tree never moves the nodes, and the `move_node` event is never fired.

I have a JSFiddle setup to demonstrate what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/PJcHm/1/ Try dragging and dropping to move Node 2 inside of Node 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after a little debugging. It looks like after releasing to drop the node inside another node, the `check_move` function is called one more time, with the level variable `p` equal to `"last"`. So I was returning false for that. The proper code is:

```
"crrm" : {
    "move" : {
        "check_move" : function (m) {
            if(m.p == "inside" || m.p == "last")
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
},
```